# Transfer mobile phone credits API

Tags: api, sms, twilio

I am planning on using Twilio to conduct surveys over SMS and IVR. The surveys will assess food security risk, and will be primarily conducted in African countries.

In order to reimburse the cost of airtime, and to incentivize respondents, I would like to transfer a small amount of credit ($0.50) upon completion of the survey.

I've found a couple of websites that support this sort of transfer, http://www.digicallingcards.com/, and http://www.transfertpays.com/en/, but (as far as I can tell) they don't offer programmatic access.

Does Twilio support this? Or is there another API that supports this kind of transaction?

Answer (score 1):

I work for Twilio and this is not something we currently provide.

When working with this kind of thing (mainly with charities etc) I see people use the concept of 'flashing'.

This is a well known concept in Africa, so it is worth considering. The idea is that you publish a number that people can ring. They then hang up when the phone rings but before it is answered - almost immediately. Your service or operators can then call that person back so they don't have to pay anything for the call!

May be worth looking at. Hope this helps!

Comment: This sounds like it would work well for voice calls, but users would still incur charges replying to SMS. Also, it doesn't give us any way to provide an incentive. Thanks for looking!